# Need to limit an attribute to 3 values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, netbeans

I have 3 tables REVIEW,PAPER and PCMEMBER and the codes for it is as mentioned below:

```
CREATE TABLE REVIEW(
due_date DATE NOT NULL,
review_date DATE NOT NULL,
recommendation VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
comment VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
pcmem_id NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
paper_id NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT review_pk PRIMARY KEY (pcmem_id,paper_id),
CONSTRAINT review_fk FOREIGN KEY(paper_id)
REFERENCES PAPER(paper_id),
CONSTRAINT review_fk1 FOREIGN KEY(pcmem_id)
REFERENCES PCMEMBER(pcmem_id));

CREATE TABLE PCMEMBER(
pcmem_id NUMBER(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
pc_fname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
pc_sname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
pc_title VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
pc_position VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
affiliation VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
pc_email VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
track_id NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pcmember_fk FOREIGN KEY(track_id)
REFERENCES TRACK(track_id));

CREATE TABLE PAPER(
paper_id NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
paper_title VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
abstract VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
paper_type VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
submission_date DATE NOT NULL,
track_id NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT paper_fk FOREIGN KEY(track_id)
REFERENCES TRACK(track_id),
CONSTRAINT chk_type CHECK(paper_type IN ('full paper','Research-in-Progress','posters')),
);
```

I'm trying to add a condition where "Each paper will be reviewed by exactly 3 PC members". Not sure what CHECK constraints I should be using? I just need this for creating tables. Thanks

Comment: You are using `check` constraints with MySQL.  Are you aware that MySQL does not enforce them?

Comment: Hi Gordon, yes I'm aware of it. Wanted to know if there's any other way I could solve this? Triggers?

Comment: For `paper_type` you can use `enum` or better a FK referencing the `paper_types` table.

Comment: Not completely sure - but `NUMBER` is not a valid type in MySQL. Use [INT, SMALLINT, TINYINT, MEDIUMINT or BIGINT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create:

- a flag `PAPER.reviewed DEFAULT 0`
- insert/update triggers to prevent changes of the flag by the client
- triggers for `REVIEW` to automaticly set (unset) the `PAPER.reviewed` flag when the related paper has (has not) exactly three reviewers (on update for both: OLD.paper_id and NEW.paper_id)
- triggers for `REVIEW` to prevent more than three reviewers per paper.

**Update**

Example for creating a trigger (prevent more than 3 reviewers per paper on insert)

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `chck_pcmem` AFTER INSERT ON `review` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF ((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM review WHERE paper_id = NEW.paper_id) > 3) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Only 3 PC members per paper';
    END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Hi paul, thank you for your reply. I'm trying to figure out the trigger statement for the above. After trying I was able to get this :
CREATE TRIGGER chck_pcmem ON REVIEW
AFTER INSERT
AS
IF EXISTS (SELECT COUNT(pcmem_id) > 3 FROM REVIEW)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('Only 3 PC members per paper.');
END
GO
Is this right?

Comment: I added an example for creating a trigger. I suggest to use a tool like HeidiSQL to create triggers and then export them.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for your help Paul!

Answer (score 2):

The problem that I see is that at *some* point(s) you're not going to have exactly 3 reviewers. When you add the first (of three) you'll only have one. You could try to make sure that your application always adds exactly three, all at once in one go, but that seems like way more hassle than it's worth.

My suggestion would be to enforce this through your application and possibly put a trigger on the table for inserts that prevents any more than three being added. In most SQL variants you could do this through a combination of a calculated column and a `CHECK` constraint, but as Gordon points out, MySQL doesn't enforce them.